# How to turn a mesh into a low poly mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, vertices

I imported a lego build from LeoCAD into Blender and it has LOTS of unnecessary vertexes.

[image]

How can I delete all the vertexes inside the mesh, but keep all the vert's on the outside, so it looks normal from the outside but without all the vert's inside

Answer (score 1):

Try the decimate modifier.

Select your mesh and go to the modifiers tab, where you can add the decimate modifier. Play around with the settings until the you are satisfied with the poly count, while retaining a good look.

Learn more about the decimate modifier here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your mesh
2. Switch to edit mode
3. Select all vertices
4. Press <kbd>P</kbd> to Separate the choose by `loose parts`. This will separate the mesh into smaller meshes
5. Switch to object mode
6. Select the meshes of the inside parts and delete them
7. Select the parts of the outside and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: I have tried something like that but it takes forever. I was hoping that there will be a quicker way.

Comment: @JustNatBro can you provide your .blend file and I'll see if there is a quicker way?